# Yii MANY_MANY additionall join condition

Tags: php, yii, many-to-many

Relation:

```
'users' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Users', 'comments_views(comment_id, user_id)', 'together' => true),
```

SQL:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments_views" "users_users"
ON (
       "t"."id"="users_users"."comment_id"
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" "users"
ON (
       "users"."id"="users_users"."user_id"
)
```

How to modify relation to get this sql:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments_views" "users_users"
ON (
       "t"."id"="users_users"."comment_id"
   AND "users_users"."user_id" = <param>
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" "users"
ON (
       "users"."id"="users_users"."user_id"
)
```

Comment: I havnt tetsed this but this may work `'users' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Users', 'comments_views(comment_id, user_id)', 'together' => true,'condition'=>"users_users.user_id=:param",'params'=>array(':param'=>$param)),`

Comment: this condition appears in where

Answer (score 1):

You should use `on` not `condition`.

```
'users' => array(
              self::MANY_MANY, 
              'Users', 
              'comments_views(comment_id, user_id)', 
              'together' => true
           ),
```

becomes

```
     'users' => array(
              self::MANY_MANY,
              'Users',
              'comments_views(comment_id, user_id)',
              'together' => true,
              'on'=>'users_users.user_id=:user_id',
              'params'=>array(':user_id' => $user_id)‌,
           ),
```

Ideally, `users_users` should be replaced with the name of the relation.

Comment: on: the ON clause. The condition specified here will be appended to the joining condition using the AND operator. Column names referenced in this option should be disambiguated. This option does not apply to MANY_MANY relations. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-options

Comment: This may as well be a limitation of the framework then. I know that it works for 1-n relations. You could write a filter in the model's `afterFind` method if you don't mind the performance impact, otherwise I don't know what to suggest.